# What is the difference between continuous ans discrete variables in an optimization problem? Natural and real numbers?

Tags: optimization, continuous, discrete-optimization

It is a rather theoretical question to better understand some definitions.

Can descision variables in descrete optimization problems be only integers?
If I have a set of real numbers which are not only natural numbers is it a continious optimization problem?

An example of a problem:

If there is a set of variables:

| animal | value |
| --- | --- |
| frog | 0.54 |
| cat | -9.12 |
| duck | 0.001 |
| dog | 4 |
| snake | -300.09 |

is that a **continious** or **descrete** problem?

From the [Wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_or_discrete_variable): A **continuous variable** is a variable whose value is obtained by measuring, i.e., one which can take on an uncountable set of values. For example, a variable over a **non-empty range of the real numbers** is continuous, **if it can take on any value in that range**. The reason is that any range of real numbers between a and b with a , b ∈ R ; a ≠ b  is uncountable. A variable is a **discrete variable** if and only if there exists a one-to-one correspondence between this variable and N, the **set of natural numbers**.

Theoretically I could say that the example is **a non-empty range of real numbers between -300.09 and 4** and see it is a **continuous** problem. From the Wikipedia definition I understand that descrete variables must belong to a set of natural numbers, so it is not my case. Or do I undestand it wrong?

Comment: [computerscience.se] is a more appropriate site for this question, as it is not about programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Mixed-integer programming is the canonical example of an discrete-optimization problems which has continuous as well as discrete variables (*mixed*). Without discrete-variables, one cannot really capture decisions or discontinuous parts on the optimization-surface (e.g. "if you set x=3; set y=5"). On the other hand, one will lose gradients which make cont. opt so attractive. Imho the general rule will say: treat as much as possible in an continuous way.